# Continue execution after raising ValueError

Tags: python, exception

How can I print a thrown ValueError but also keep going for the next iteration? I searched some but mostly they are about try catch blocks. Consider my code:

Attempt #1

```
for i in range(15):
    if i == 3:
        raise ValueError("error message")
    print(i)
```

Attempt #2

```
for i in range(15):
    if i == 3:
        try:
            raise ValueError("error message")
        except:
            pass
    print(i)
```

In #1 I cannot continue after 3. In #2 I don't get any thrown error. How can I throw the ValueError but also keep going for the next iteration? I want to throw ValueError to the screen but keep printing the items.

Comment: If you just want to print an error message and continue execution, then you don't need to raise an exception. You can just `print` an error message.

Comment: You can *either* throw an error or continue execution. You can't do both.

Comment: You have to decide if you want to throw an exception which will stop the local execution and go back up the stack to the next matching exception handling block, or continue the execution at the current position. Both is not possible.

Comment: Throwing an exception *means* abandoning execution and continuing after an exception *means* suppressing it. Your goals do not make sense together. What behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to create a interpreter session. We do know that we get an error ( valueerror example in this case) and keep using the interpreter. I would like to achieve to that. Is it really not possible that using try except block ?

Comment: I want to write a function that reads statements one by one, and if there is a wrong statement I should raise the error, however I should keep reading the next statement. I guess it is exactly the same as I asked in the question

Comment: You already raise an error and proceed running, by suppressing it. What *observable behavior* do you want from keeping the error „alive“ as well? Do you want the computation to emit the error *when done*? What do you want to happen if *another* error occurs when resuming? Do you want an error to be reported/printed?

Comment: I want to report that just like Interpreter does it. So just printing is not enough. If you write weird "2 3" to python repl it would say syntax error but just keep asking the next statement. My implementation raises it and stops asking statement if something is wrong

Comment: So your actual question is "how do I print a traceback without aborting execution"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I dont know what print a traceback without aborting execution is , But it seems like that is my question. I'll look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the `ValueError` on your screen during your loop, consider printing it.

For example:

```py
for i in range(15):
    if i == 3:
        try:
            raise ValueError("error message")
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
    print(i)
```